# how to make mutiple typeconverter for OBJECTS in room DB

Tags: android, odoo-9, android-room, android-architecture-components

Getting Object as response from Odoo server using JSON RPC. I want to convert Object to mutiple primittive types. As room database does not support object this conversion has to done to save data in database. Can anyone help me out posting source code below

Model Db creation:

```
@Entity(tableName = "ryot")

public class RyotMasterJsonRpcResult {
public Integer getIds() {
    return ids;
}

public void setIds(Integer ids) {
    this.ids = ids;
}

@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
private Integer ids;
@SerializedName("old_edit_by_id")
@Expose
@Ignore
private Object oldEditById = null;
@SerializedName("create_date")
@Expose
private Object createDate;
@SerializedName("ryot_number")
@Expose
private Object ryotNumber;
@SerializedName("display_name")
@Expose
private Object displayName;
public List<Object> getOldEditById() {
    if (oldEditById != null && !oldEditById.equals("false")) {
        return (List<Object>) oldEditById;
    }
    return null;

}

public void setOldEditById(List<Object> oldEditById) {
    this.oldEditById = oldEditById;
}

public Object getCreateDate() {
    return createDate;
}

public void setCreateDate(String createDate) {
    this.createDate = createDate;
}

public Object getRyotNumber() {
    return ryotNumber;
}

public void setRyotNumber(String ryotNumber) {
    this.ryotNumber = ryotNumber;
}

public Object getDisplayName() {
    return displayName;
}

public void setDisplayName(String displayName) {
    this.displayName = displayName;
}
```

Typer converter:

```
public class CommonConverter {


@TypeConverter
public static Object fromString(String value) {

    return value;
}

@TypeConverter
public static String toString(Object data) {
    return (String) data;
}
@TypeConverter
public static Object fromInt(Integer value) {

    return value;
}

@TypeConverter
public static Integer toInt(Object data) {

    return (Integer) data;
}
@TypeConverter
public static Object fromBoolean(Boolean value) {

    return value;
}

@TypeConverter
public static Boolean toBoolean(Object data) {
    return (Boolean)data;
}

}
```

Getting error as:

```
Error:(492, 29) error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to 
String
Error:(492, 29) error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to 
Boolean
Error:(492, 29) error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to 
integer
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to convert Object to mutiple primittive types.

That is not possible. In your code, nobody, including you, has any idea what to convert an `Object` into: a `boolean`? an `int`? a `String`? something else?

The best solution is to get rid of all references to `Object`, and fix your RPC serialization to use more specific types. Room itself is perfectly capable of handling `boolean`, `int`, and `String`.

The next-best solution is to not have your RPC response be an `@Entity`. After all, there is no requirement that your RPC result be something that *always* can be represented by a single SQLite table. Treat the RPC response as a [DTO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) and treat the Room entity as a separate DTO. Then, your Room entity does not need to worry about bizarre `Object` responses from the RPC.

The next-next-best solution is to have different `@TypeConverter` classes per data type (one for `boolean`, one for `String`, one for `int`), and apply `@TypeConverters` on a per-field basis in your entity, so you dictate the specific type converter to use for each field.

Comment: Third Solution i have tried but i don't know how response come so only i assigned as a object . and i created common Type Converter for both Boolean and int and String ...what i do

Comment: @Rajakrishnan: "i don't know how response come" -- that would seem to be the core of your problem. Addressing that is what I referred as the best solution in my answer. "what i do" -- talk to whoever is maintaining the server and work with them to come up with a better, fully-specified RPC protocol.